# What is the name for the walkable area above a stadium?

Tags: single-word-requests

Generally, in some indoor stadiums or arenas or theaters, if you will...there is a walkable space in the roof or the area directly above the stage...from which many technical activities are performed...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The general term you might refer to is *Catwalk*, but there must be a specific term for stage.

Comment: If it is directly above the stage as part of the production set, it might be *scaffolding*, but *catwalk* is what I had in mind as well.

Comment: Catwalk (ktwôk) n. A narrow, often elevated walkway, as on the sides of a bridge or in the flies **above a theater stage**. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/catwalk)

Comment: A photo from a good angle: http://www.austinchronicle.com/binary/5050/arts_feature99-6.jpg

Comment: I've always heard *catwalk* for the theater.

Comment: And here was I thinking a catwalk was just the runway that fashion models prance up and down! Never knew it meant anything else (apparently it's also a similar structure on a whaling boat). Learn summat new ev’ry day!

Comment: I thought I had marked the answer.. Updating it...

Answer (score 11):

Above the stage is the Rope Loft or Fly Loft. To day it's usually referred to as The Grid. The working/walking areas are usually referred to as The Bridge. If you say "Up on the grid" riggers and techs will know what you're talking about.

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_system

Comment: +1 When I was active in theatre ('65-'95 in the US) the *grid* was specifically the system of cris-crossing beams from which scenic and lighting elements were suspended; the area above that, where people worked, was *the flies*--you might say someone was working *on the grid* or *in the flies*. A *catwalk* was a section of the *grid* boarded over to make work and movement less precarious.

Answer (score 3):

I would refer to such a platform as a ***["gantry"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gantry)***.

> A bridge-like overhead structure with a platform supporting equipment such as a crane, signals, or cameras: 
> *"the TV cameras on gantries alongside the 17th and 18th holes"*

Comment: A gantry is just a frame that things are mounted on: it's not necessarily walkable.

Comment: Not necessarily, I agree.  But they can be.

Answer (score 0):

Castles and cathedrals have “[allures/alurs/alures](http://en.mimi.hu/architecture/allure.html)” aka “[wall-walks](http://en.mimi.hu/architecture/wall-walk.html)” around their perimeters near/at/above roof-level to facilitate foot-traffic and movement of weapons/equipment.  While they wouldn’t apply to theaters/stages and are perhaps not designed for modern technical activities, stadiums and arenas probably have similar elevated walkable ways around their perimeters.